# Fiancée not on the mortgage but wants to be on the title

Tags: mortgage, loans

Just to clarify: She cannot be on the mortgage because she is on another mortgage with her mother.  We will be paying for the mortgage together.

As she is paying for the mortgage with me, she wants to be on the title. I am currently only finished with loan pre-approval.

If I add her on the title when I purchase the house, I am assuming this would affect the loan process as I read that lenders don't want someone that's not on the mortgage on the title in case I can't make the payments and they need to foreclose.

- When is the earliest I can add her to the title?
- Do I need to finish paying the whole mortgage before I can add?

Comment: Don't.  If your relationship goes bad you're setting yourself up for trouble.

Comment: Why 'can't she be on the mortgage'? Someone can be on more than one mortgage!

Comment: If you are in a community property state and you get married it won't matter if she is on the title, she will likely co-own the house anyway.

Comment: On the title: has partial ownership. Not on the mortgage: has no responsibility.  If you really want to do this, discuss all the possible failure modes in advance, agree on what should happen in those cases, and get a lawyer to put that agreement in an enforceable form. I know that doesn't sound romantic, but it's the best way to protect both parties.

Comment: I'm agreeing with the previous posters advice to protect yourself. Make sure that you understand the potential for loss on your part and you have a clear plan in place for how finances are handled. Find out if her reason for wanting to be on the title is purely emotional. If she isn't on the mortgage, she isn't really making the payments.

Comment: What country (or U.S. state) are you in?  Different jurisdictions treat marital property differently.  In some states, it matters if both of you "will be paying for the mortgage together."

Comment: Absolutely definitely discuss with your girlfriend what will happen to the house if you split up. When you've agreed that, hire a lawyer to put it in writing and both sign it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding her to the title after the fact could potentially trigger clauses in your contract with the lender, such as the [Due-on-Sale clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due-on-sale_clause). While banks are not obligated to act on such clauses, they most certainly can in many cases which could result in sudden and very large financial implications for you. In general you should avoid any changes which might trigger these types of clauses because you cannot be sure how your bank may react.